# Use the Law of Large Number to compute the probability of at least 49% heads on n, as n goes to infinity.

Tags: probability, statistics

Q: Use the Law of Large Number to compute the probability of at least 49% heads on n, as n goes to infinity.

From the Text, there is an example that is similar to this question which is this↓

Answer (score 0):

The law of large numbers is that if a random variable has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then for every $\epsilon > 0$ the sample mean $X_n$ satisfies $P(|X_n - \mu| \ge \epsilon) \le \frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon}$. So the probability of heads being out of the $49\% - 51\%$ range is less than or equal to $\frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon}$. As $n\to\infty$, $\frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon} \to 0$, so the probability of at least $49\%$ heads is $1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Do you mean 1 as in 100% as n goes to infinity? I am confused.

Comment: Yes, as n goes to infinity the probability is 100%